# Personal assistant

Tags: python, wolframalpha

I was following an online tutorial on how to build a personal assistant in python but I got stuck in the process. I started simply by importing wikipedia and wolframalpha libraries, I am using pycharm with python 3.6.

This is my code:

```
import wolframalpha
import wikipedia

while True:
    question = input("Q: ")

    try:
        #wolframalpha
        app_id = "APP ID CODE" (here I inserted my personal code)
        client = wolframalpha.Client(app_id)
        res = client.query(question)
        answer = next(res.results).text
        print(answer)
    except:
        #wikipedia
        print(wikipedia.summary(question, sentences = 3))
```

I run it more than once and discovered that the wolfram part doesn't work and I can't see why

Comment: Remove the `except:`. And test it.

Comment: Try moving 'app_id' and 'client' declaration out of the while loop. You should declare it only once.

Comment: Testing without the `except:` I get an SSL:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED